# Why can the template not be instantiated in this piece of C++ code?

Tags: c++, templates, most-vexing-parse, non-type-template-parameter

As titled, why is the template instantiation in the main function wrong? I use Clang++ with flag "-std=c++2a". Did I use anything in a wrong way here?

```
template<int, int>
void f(int) { std::cout << "int"; };

template<class T> 
void g() {  // dependent-name.
  f<0, T()>(0);
}

int main() {
  g<int>();  // wrong here, why?
}
```

Error messages from Clang:

```
test.cc:41:3: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
  f<0, T()>(0);
  ^~~~~~~~~
test.cc:48:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'g<int>' requested here
  g<int>(); // "int";
  ^
test.cc:35:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for 2nd
      template parameter
void f(int) { std::cout << "int"; };
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `f<0, T{}>(0);` and `f<0, (T())>(0);` both work... Most-vexing parse in a template argument? Wow.

Comment: gcc has a better message; "ambiguous template argument for non-type template parameter is treated as function type"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This instantiation:

```
f<0, T()>(0);
```

for `T=int` gives `int()` for the second explicit template parameter. This is basically a vexing parse, and so the argument is treated as a function type. This is not the same as an `int` object, which is what `f` expects for its template parameters.

Instead, you can instantiate it like this:

```
f<0, T{}>(0);
```

so that the second template parameter is an `int` object.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n53vaE).